# WordPress Api + Android

Tags: android, wordpress

I have a blog which is written in WordPress but not hosted on Wordpress.com, and I would like to develop an Android app to interact with this blog via the Wordpress `REST Api`. I searched in the Wordpress developper documentation and it seems that you can interact with this API only through Wordpress.com.

I have also made some Google searches and I found that many plugins provide this functionality but I don't know which one to use.

My Android app will interact with this blog. It will get all the blog posts, comment, post comments. If the user is an admin, he can create new posts. Note that I could simply create an RSS feed and everything would be alright but I want to take advantage of the Wordpress API.

What are the best solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One Doubt, if its API Means you can Use JSON or XML for Android

First Check for JSON

Check [This](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/)

other wise use that API and Create a Custom RestFul web services which Reads Data form that API,.. Automatically.

Better to Use API for Fast Results..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to develop this app yourself? Because if there's none, you should check the [official app by Wordpress in the Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=es&id=org.wordpress.android). I use it for some self hosted blogs and it's very helpful.

Comment: Well maybe I am not clear but my app is not hosted in wp. My app does not have any relation with wordpress.

Comment: Yeah, but the application is not hosted in wordpress.com

Comment: You want an Android app that lets you manage your self hosted Wordpress blog, right? The app I linked lets you do that.

Comment: Well, as I said before the blog is not hosted in wordpress.com or wordpress.org. I was searching for a REST+JSON Api that helps me interact with the app.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand - to get required functions you need [WordPress REST API (Version 2)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) and one of plugins for authentication: Basic-Auth of OAuth1 [WP-API on GitHub](https://github.com/WP-API)
For more details please see official documentation on [v2.wp-api.org](http://v2.wp-api.org)